# Difference between of intermediate_ip_address and private_ip_address in bluemix container groups

Tags: docker, containers, ibm-cloud

This question relates to IBM's docker container group service, which allows load balancing across multiple docker containers created using a common docker image.

After a bluemix docker container group is created, you can inspect its metadata using the `cf ic inspect <container id>` command.

A subsection of the output of this command reads as follows:

```
"Loadbalancer": {
    "intermediate_ip_address": "an ip address", 
    "private_ip_address": "a different ip address"
},
```

It would seem that the intention is that at least one of these addresses can be used as the load balancer endpoint in the sense that sending requests to such an address will spread the requests on the members of the docker container group.

The specific question is, what is the distinction between these addresses? What is the intended use for each?

Answer (score 2):

The private ip is the address of the LB within the private network subnet for that container space.  That's the one to be used to access the group via that LB from other containers in that space.  It's effectively a direct connection within the subnet.

The intermediate ip address is the translation address used for secure routing by the gorouter (by way of isolation firewalls and translation tables) to access the group.  It will work from within the space, but will require addition lookups and hops (i.e. latency).

Found a picture: https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/containers/container_planning_org_ov.html

The private ip (shown in that picture in the box marked "Container Group Load Balancer") is usable within your space.  The intermediate ip (not shown there) is really meant for the line between the "Private Network Gateway" box and the "Go-Router/reverse proxy" box.